# Streams : Calculate the difference of totals in one go

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, bigdecimal

I have a `List<LedgerEntry> ledgerEntries` and I need to calculate the sum of creditAmount and debitAmount.

```
class LedgerEntry{
 private BigDecimal creditAmount;
 private BigDecimal debitAmount;

 //getters and setters
}
```

I have implemented this as,

```
BigDecimal creditTotal = ledgeredEntries.stream().map(p ->p.getCreditAmount()).
reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
BigDecimal debitTotal = ledgeredEntries.stream().map(p ->p.getDebitAmount()).
reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
BigDecimal sumCreditDebit = creditTotal.subtract(debitTotal);
```

This looks like I'm iterating over the `List` twice. Is there a way to get this done in one go without having to steam the list twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subtract the individual amounts in `map` and then `sum` them using `reduce`

```
ledgerEntries.stream()
    .map(e->e.getCreditAmount().subtract(e.getDebitAmount())
    .reduce(0,BigDecimal::add);
```

Comment: Thanks. That was fast.
On the same note, what if I need the two values separately (ie: creditTotal and debitTotal separately).

Comment: @Krishan Welcome. Can you elaborate on what you mean by needing the two values separately?

Comment: Just like in my question, if I need creditTotal and debitTotal values separately to be used later on, can I do that by just iterating through the list once? using stream() twice for the same list seems like iterating over the list twice? Or is it not the case and compiler does some magic to optimise streaming?

Comment: @Krishnan No there won't be some magic as these are separate operations. You can't get the difference and the totals in one `stream` operation IMO. Even if you could, it wouldn't be a readable solution. These would require two separate stream operations if you want to keep a track of the intermediate totals as well. I'll take a look. You can post a new question (new post) meanwhile to address these questions since your question did not mention that you also want to save the the individual totals.

Comment: @Krishan Noted. You should also mention the additional requirement to calculate their difference in the new question.

Answer (score 6):

Just reduce it to:

```
BigDecimal sumCreditDebit = ledgeredEntries.stream().map(p -> p.getCreditAmount()
        .subtract(p.getDebitAmount()))
        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
BigDecimal result = ledgeredEntries.stream().map(p -> p.getCreditAmount().subtract(p.getDebitAmount()))
            .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is now a completely new answer from your initial attempt. More of a repost than a fix.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution:

```
    BigDecimal result = array.stream().reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO,
            (bigDecimal, ledgerEntry) -> bigDecimal.add(ledgerEntry.getCreditAmount()).subtract(ledgerEntry.getDebitAmount()),
            BigDecimal::add);
```

I get the difference between each credit debit pair and add them together using `reduce`.